# LinkedIn People Search API

Tags: linkedin-api

I integrated LinkedIn People Search API in my iOS app. I am sening requests to this API, but I am getting access denials from LinkedIn. In the documentation, LinkedIn says that this API requires the developer to be registered as a LinkedIn Partner, in order to be able to access it.

I filled in the LinkedIn Partnership Program form (https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply) in order to get access to LinkedIn People Search API. I did that several times during a period of 2-3 months, and I get this time of rejection every time: http://screencast.com/t/f7VDzDc43gK Can anybody help me with an answer about how I can become a LinkedIn Partner?

This image will help:
[image: Helpful image]

Comment: Kindly add some code what you have tried

Comment: Here is the code: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gkw8J.png

Comment: That's not code, that's the response you get. Show us your source code. (And don't use a screen shot; copy/paste the actual code.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LinkedIn People Search API access denials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326051/linkedin-people-search-api-access-denials)