# LinkedIn People Search API access denials

Tags: linkedin-api

I integrated LinkedIn People Search API in my iOS app. I am sening requests to this API, but I am getting access denials from LinkedIn.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

people search is a privileged api that require linkedin approval. you can [request it here](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs).